# R function - summarize 2 variables at the same time

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have the following code. In short, my files is just sales by date, company, etc. I would like to summarize and group my data, however I can't get the summarization to summarize both my total sales and quantities at the same time. I must be missing something easy. Right now the code does summarize my salesdollar field, but I also want a new "total_Quantity" field created that summarizes the field "quantity" in my dataset. How would I put that it?

```
    Sales_2019<- read.csv ("C:/Users/anwei/Desktop/salesFINAL.csv")
    Sales_2019

    attach(Sales_2019)
    library(timeDate)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)

    SalesSum_fin<- Sales_2019 %>% 
      group_by(Store, Classification, SalesDate) %>% 
      summarize(OverallSales = 
                  sum(SalesDollars, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: SalesSum_fin<- Sales_2019 %>% group_by(Store, Classification, SalesDate) %>% summarise(OverallSales = sum(SalesDollars, na.rm = TRUE), TotalQuantity = sum(Quantity, na.rm = TRUE))- Try it out! It will work

Comment: you may also use `across`, see [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)

Comment: Can you add a sample input dataframe?

Comment: I'm all set! Thank you Luiy_coder! That helped.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out! You just have to use summarise from dplyr.
For your clarity, This is the data I've considered.

[image]

I have just excluded date column. You can add it in your script.

```
Store = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
Classification = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC")
SalesDollars = c(1234, 345, 567, 789, 432)
Quantity = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Sales_2019 = data.frame(Store, Classification, SalesDollars, Quantity, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

SalesSum_fin<- Sales_2019 %>% 
  group_by(Store, Classification) %>% 
  summarise(OverallSales = sum(SalesDollars, na.rm=TRUE),
            Quantity     = sum(Quantity, na.rm = TRUE))
```

This is the output:-
[image]